# get everything after a particular string in python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
url="www.example.com/thedubaimall"
```

I want to save everything that comes after`com/` that is I need only `thedubaimall`

How can i do it with regular expression??

Comment: @ClasG beginners start with basic stuffs

Comment: True, but having someone handing you a book, doesn't mean you've learnt anything about writing. You're still a beginner... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use regular expression, you use `re.findall`:

```
re.findall('(?<=com/).*$', "www.example.com/thedubaimall")
# ['thedubaimall']
```

Some speed tests with @DeepSpace's suggestion:

```
%timeit re.findall('(?<=com/).*$', "www.example.com/thedubaimall")
# The slowest run took 7.57 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 µs per loop

%timeit re.findall('com/(.*)', "www.example.com/thedubaimall")
# The slowest run took 6.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 992 ns per loop

%timeit "www.example.com/thedubaimall".partition(".com/")[2]
# The slowest run took 7.87 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 204 ns per loop
```

Looks like @DeepSpace's suggestion is a bit faster, and @Kevin's answer is much faster.

Comment: I believe that the regex can be greatly simplified to `'com/(.+)'` (or `'com/(.*)'`, based on whether OP wants an empty list or an empty string for  `'www.example.com/'`)

Answer (score 7):

Obligatory "what if you *didn't* use regex?" answer:

```
>>> url="www.example.com/thedubaimall"
>>> url.partition(".com/")[2]
'thedubaimall'
```